# MS Edge 14+ CSS helper does not work

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I want to change CSS specific to MS Edge. I tried some method introduced in this website ([browser strangeness](https://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html)) but it doesn't work.

Please check my sample in [codepen](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/ELKmqK).

html

`<div class='test'>ahahaha</div>`

css

```
.test {
 color : blue;
 }

  /* MS Edge */
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto)
and (not (-ms-accelerator:true))
and (not (-webkit-text-stroke:initial)) {
.test { color : red; } }

/* IE 10+ */
  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) 
  { .test { color : red;  }  }
```

As I'm a Mac user, I use [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/start) extention to check IE and Edge. With above code, IE works fine but Edge does not.

Is there anyway to specify Edge in CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: Before digging into how to detect Edge via CSS, any chance you can provide me with the interop issue you're using a workaround for? A jsbin or codepen of the issue would be great, or you can provide a bug to us via bugs.microsoftedge.com

Comment: @gregwhitworth What is  interop issue?

Comment: Sorry, what bug or issue are you trying to work around, as I'd rather try to solve it not using a browser detecting hack as when we fix the bug Edge will still be broken because you'll be serving different content to it than other browsers.